# SQLiteLog: (1) near "Result": syntax error

Tags: mysql, android-studio, cursor

Здравствуйте. Пишу курсор для заполнения listview. Ни как не могу найти ошибку. Я ведь правильно понимаю, что ошибка синтаксическая (sql)?

```
 public  Cursor GetInfoAboutUsers(){
    String sqlQuery ="SELECT User._id as id , User.name as name, Result.Distance as distance, Result.Weight as weight, Result.Fat as fat Result.Date as date FROM User INNER JOIN Result ON User._id=Result.UserID";
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли запятую перед последним столбцом:

```
 public  Cursor GetInfoAboutUsers(){
String sqlQuery ="SELECT User._id as id , User.name as name, Result.Distance as distance, Result.Weight as weight, Result.Fat as fat, Result.Date as date FROM User INNER JOIN Result ON User._id=Result.UserID";
return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
}
```